# django multi-tenancy and wildcard subdomains

Tags: django, multi-tenant

I want to offer `client.domain.com` for every client on the site. In practice, `client.domain.com` is equivalent to `www.domain.com/client/` (which I know how to handle in urls but isn't what I want).

1. Can I use `django-subdomains` to allow this sort of wildcarding without defining `SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS` since I don't want to try and enumerate for all *clients*.
2. I'm currently using Apache. I don't want to create a new virtual host for each *client* as well. Is there a generic way to make `client.mydomain.com` work?

Appreciate all pointers to executing #1 and #2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have to enumerate all clients, according to the [example configuration in the docs](https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-configuration), `django-subdomains` will use the `ROOT_URLCONF` when no entry in `SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS` matches.
2. I'm not very familiar with Apache, but you should be able to use a wildcard `ServerAlias`:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.example.com
       ServerAlias *.example.com
       ...
   </VirtualHost>
   ```